# How to get current width of highcharts column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to place a label on a highcharts column chart, but I want it to sit above and between the columns of a two series chart.

I do not want to change the width of the column, only retrieve it's current width.

I have the code working to place the labels above the column with the highest value, which is working fine, but what I can't figure out is how to find the width of the column so I can position the label correctly in the centre of them.

Searching has got me this bit of code to set the width:

```
 chart.series[0].data[0].graphic.attr({
        width:50
    });
```

And this should return the value:

```
chart.series[0].data[0].graphic.width
```

Although the code I need is going to be inside the plotOptions formatter and should probably look closer to this:

```
this.series.chart.series[0].yData[this.point.index].graphic.width
```

If it's any help the context of the above code is:

```
var thisVal = this.point.y;
var i = this.point.x % trendCategories2.length;
var prevVal = this.series.chart.series[0].yData[this.point.index];
var nextVal = this.series.chart.series[1].yData[this.point.index];
var highVal;
var output;
console.log(this.series.chart.series[0].yData[this.point.index].graphic.width);
```

The console.log is the bit I'm having trouble with. I've tried various permutations of it to get the width but they have all return undefined, I'm pretty sure it's something silly that I'm missing.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: can you paste the html code?

Comment: There's not really anything more to add, it's the format of the code in the last snippet which has me stumped. But I'll add some more context if you think it'll help.

Comment: i asked for html! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I've figured out how to get the width of the columns, the syntax was way off and I ended up having to go through the series object to see what metrics were available.

```
var colWidth = this.series.columnMetrics.width;
```

The above returns the width of the column, that syntax works inside the

```
plotOptions -> dataLabels -> formatter function
```

Hopefully it helps someone else at some point.